# SignalR group notification does not work on IE9 unless start({ transport: 'longPolling' })

Tags: signalr

I tested a simple SignalR MVC 4 app on IE9. The app uses group notifications:

```
public class Booking
{
    public void BookFlight(String from, String to, string ConnectionId)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();

        hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage("Started ... " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        string groupName = "Z"; // "g" + ConnectionId;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
        // Book first leg
        hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(String.Format("Booking flight: {0}-{1} ...", from, to));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Book return 
        hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(String.Format("Booking flight: {0}-{1} ...", to, from));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // Book car rent 
        hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(String.Format("Booking car rent: {0}-{1} ...", to, from));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Some return value
        hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage("Finished ... " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage("Flight booked successfully. Total Time = " + (DateTime.Now - (DateTime)HttpContext.Current.Session["StartTime"]).ToString());
    }
}

namespace SignalrProgressDemo.Common
{
   public class ProgressHub : Hub
   {
       public override Task OnConnected()
       {
          string groupName = "Z"; 
          return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
       }
...
```

Here is the client code:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#bookButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax("/Home/BookFlight?from=tlv&to=fco&connectionId=" + $.connection.hub.id);
        });

        var progressHub = $.connection.progressHub;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        progressHub.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            $("#msg").html(message);
        };


        $.connection.hub.start(); //IE9 does NOT work
        //$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }); //IE9 works OK
    });
```

As indicated in the client code IE9 displays only messages sent to All and does NOT display messages sent to group "Z".

It works OK (=receives group messages) only when the connection.hub starts with {transport: 'longPolling'}.

**Problems/Questions**

1. Forcing longpolling prevent using WebSockets in Chrome, Opera.
2. It is unclear why explicitly forcing longpolling helps since IE9 will use longpolling anyway (since it is the only method the actually works).

I did notice this scenario which shows there there might be a relation between the longpolling and WebSockets in the server:

a. Use $.connection.hub.start()

b. Open IE9.

c. Test - works OK

d. Open Chrome (will use WebSockets) - Test - works OK

e. Test IE9 - does not work.

Comment: Where are you adding the client to the group "Z"?

Comment: @halter73 - I added the Hub code where the client is added to group "Z" to the original post.